# Nutrition: qualitative or quantitative?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've been tasked with copy-editing some text that includes the following:

> [...] makes it easy for you to cook with the **maximum nutrition**.

I'm unsure about the correctness of the phrase "maximum nutrition". I've always considered nutrition (in this kind of context) to be of a qualitative nature where "good nutrition" refers to a good balance of nutrients in a meal or diet and "bad nutrition" the opposite.

"Maximum nutrition", though, seems to treat nutrition as a quantitative concept, implying that more nutrition is better which doesn't seem right.

Is there a definitive answer to the question of whether nutrition should be considered qualitative or quantitative in the context of health/diet-focused writing, and is the concept of "maximum nutrition" a valid one?

Comment: It sounds odd to me, too, but I haven't a definitive answer for you.

Comment: [whfoods.org](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=george&dbid=265) gives an example of the use of 'maximum' with two nouns referring to two concepts which may be regarded as 'semi-quantifiable' or  'orderable' (this diet is more nutritious/enjoyable  than that): _The Healthiest Way of Eating is eating for maximum nutrition and enjoyment_. Ordering is quite common where a well-defined scale would be difficult to establish (tiredness / alertness / happiness / wellness etc). There are a lot of Google Hits for "maximum nutrition", but many of them are for the proper noun.

Comment: The "the" makes this phrase more awkward. "cook with maximum nutrition" is more natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the dictionary definition, ***nutrition*** is

> : the process of eating the right kind of food so you can grow properly and be healthy
>
> :  the act or process of nourishing or being nourished; specifically :  the sum of the processes by which an animal or plant takes in and utilizes food substances
>
> <sub>*source: [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nutrition)*</sub>

With that definition in mind, the idea of maximizing nutrition can be justified: you want to get the most possible nourishment from a given item, or you want to consume items that give you the most nourishment.

However, cooking *with* maximum nutrition doesn't make sense; you don't gain nourishment from the act of cooking.  Instead, you want to cook ***for*** maximum nutrition.

(Speaking anecdotally, I would say that normally I would expect to hear "maximum nutritional value" instead of "maximum nutrition.")